# Compress Mat into Jpeg And save the result into memory

Tags: c++, opencv, jpeg, mat

I know that the function `cv::imwrite` can compress a `cv::Mat` into Jpeg and save it to a file. But now I want to save it into memory, like a array of `uchar`. So, I can send the array to another one ,and it can write the data into a jpeg file. Is there any one can help me out?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since You did not specify a programming language. I am going to give you the answer in C++.

```
    std::vector<uchar> buff;//buffer for coding
    std::vector<int> param(2);
    param[0] = cv::IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY;
    param[1] = 80;//default(95) 0-100
    cv::imencode(".jpg", mat, buff, param);
```

Comment: I have trie this,but if i write buff into a jpeg file,i cant't open the file as a jpeg picture.When i tried to open it ,a error occured.

Comment: with jpg you cant use for example 'imshow'.. you have to 'decode' it first.

Comment: if he writes the received data as byte stream to some file, I think it would work.  The point is " DO NOT EVER deal with JPEG stream as an image. It is NOT an image

Comment: When you say image,do you mean a picture file or data of Mat type?

Comment: sorry I meant Mat or raw image data or bitmap

Comment: no. jpg contain header infotmaion inside it but it is a compressed file.
for example if you open a zip file in notpad what gonna you see?? a rubbish text. right? even if the original file is a nice poem before compressing. same for jpg.. you can conseider a bmp file is like txt file and jpg file is like the .zip file of that txt

Comment: So if i  use` imencode(".jpg,mat ,buff1 ,param")` to compress Mat into buff1 ,and i also use `fopen`and`fread`funciton to read data  from a nomal jpg file named a.jpg into buff2.What's the difference between this two kinds of data int buff1 and buff2?

Comment: Theoretically they are the same. In practise you gonna find some differences because of the compression algorithm and the compression ratio

Answer (score 1):

If your choice of programming language is Java,  then use:

`Highgui.imencode("jpg", mat, buffer)`.

Comment: OP's question is tagged [tag:c++]

Comment: how to do in javascript or typescript?